# sikuli : image in flash pop up cannot be found

Tags: detection, flash, sikuli

I'm doing a bot for a flash game, using sikuli.api within java code. Everything is very cool with sikuli but I got a real problem.

My bot is already doing lot of thing, I just check there are already 85 exists, find or findall looking perfectly in my application, in simplie built and with the jar (you can test it if you play to Forge of empire), BUT :

Sometime according to mouse position, the game produce a little flash pop-up (should have a technical flash name but I don't know flash technology). This pop-up give an information about the building that is under the mouse pointer.

My problem is that I cannot detect what is inside this pop-p, like if sikuli cannot catch a flash pop-up...

If I make a copy screen of the game with this pop up, with the IDE, I can detect the pop-up (and check the theresold of similarity). But analyzing the real screen, sikuli cannot detect the pop-up.
The application looking at this screen copy "see" correctly the pop-up.

Possible clue or at least something special : if I do an "highligth(1)" of the region where there is the pop-up when there is this pop-up, the flash pop-up disappear whereas it should only disappear when moving the mouse.
Without highlight, the pop up do not disappear while trying to analyse it.

Before you ask :
- the image reference is at the right place and found by the code
- similarity parameter is correct and check with the sikulix-IDE and with the screen copy

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the underlying technology is irrelevant as Sikuli only "sees" what is actually displayed on the screen so you shouldn't worry whether that's flash or anything else.

Highlighting an area should not in any way activate a mouse movement. From what you describe however, my only guess is that you somehow miss the pop-up? Does it appear and disappear quickly? If that's the issue, have a look [here](http://eugenesautomation.blogspot.com.au/2015/01/optimizing-pattern-matching-using-sikuli_21.html) where I discuss few ways that can speed up your search.